# How to improve my Java APP for better performance?

Tags: java, spring, performance, memory, jvm

I have some questions about performances for those kind of stations (using Spring Boot for my project now). As you will understand soon, I'm a bit confused while learning lots of informations at once. So i will share my different kind of questions and some of my tests to understand the flow and help others who are confused like me:

1) Reading application.properties like this:

```java
@Value("${foo.name}")
private String name;
```

vs reading properties starting with poo into the class and getting its value with getters.

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class FooBean {
   private String name;
   private String age;
   ...

   // setters and getters
}
```

1a) So which approach is faster and why? Can you explain it with memory performances if there is a difference
1b) Also lets say i use FooBean approach and in the Example1 class i need only FooBean's name. Should i inject FooBean to the Example1 class while i need only 1 field of it or should i use @Value style and get only specific field, which has better performance now?

2) Should i declare fields of FooBean as static? Lets see an example:

Configuration class:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "openstack")
@Data
@Validated
public class OpenStackBean {

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private String container;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private String keystoneEndpoint;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private String swiftEndpoint;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private String tenantName;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private String userName;
}
```

And lets say this class only will be used by its Service:

```java
@Service
public class OpenStackService implements IOpenStackService {

    private OpenStackBean openStackBean;

    @Autowired
    public OpenStackService(OpenStackBean openStackBean) {
        this.openStackBean = openStackBean;
    }

...
...


private OSClientV2 authenticate(Facing perspective) throws AuthenticationException {
        return OSFactory
                .builderV2()
                .endpoint(openStackBean.getKeystoneEndpoint())
                .credentials(openStackBean.getUserName(), blowfish.decryptString(openStackBean.getPassword()))
                .tenantName(openStackBean.getTenantName())
                .perspective(perspective)
                .withConfig(Config
                        .newConfig()
                        .withConnectionTimeout(applicationBean.getConnectionTimeout())
                        .withReadTimeout(applicationBean.getReadTimeout())
                        .withMaxConnections(10)
                        .withMaxConnectionsPerRoute(2))
                .authenticate();
    }
```

If i am correct the scenario will be like this:

1) In this case I will be injecting those configurations as instance. 
2) So every class (lets say i have 10.000 users in a minute and this class will be created 10.000 times) will create their own configuration in the stack, will it and when it completes, deletes it, so memory is free again.
3) But because there will be so many request, doesn't it make memory problems?

If this flow is correct, than should i create OpenStackBean's field as static and inject it as `private static OpenStackBean` ? This will be hold in the heap once and all users will get it from there. Which performance is better?

3) Here is my some test results which makes me start thinking about String manipulations' and injection's performance. Here is sample stress test using JMeter and visualizing with Java VisualVM

[image: Before the test]

Sending 10.000 requests

[image: after the test - report 1]
[image: after the test - report 2]
[image: after the test - report 3]

But i don't understand why heap usage always increases. Here is how APP works:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity all(@ApiIgnore GameParam param) {
        try {
            // get games by categories by default
            if (param.getPageNo() == null) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(gameService.getGamesByCategories(), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
```

All requests entered this condition and called:

2) This function is called. Since categorizedGameList is static (which is initializied on the APP startup, and will be updated from the remote server daily by a Scheduler), all requests directly return with 2 steps. GameList is in the Heap, so no new instance will be created.

GameList --> 14 KB (14173 byte)

```java
@Override
    public List<CategoryVO> getGamesByCategories() {
        if (categorizedGameList != null) {
            return categorizedGameList;
        } else {
            return getAndCategorizeGames();
        }
    }
```

3) So why heap increases 300MB (from 100 to 400) after 10000 requests? This means 30 KB is created in the memory for every requests.

3a) What exactly happens when a request comes to an endpoint? Are all instance variables of the APP will be created or only visited classes will be created? I was thinking like this:

- User creates a connection to my endpoint
- User will be routed to my Controller class, so this class is created in the memory. (Not all the classes of the application). Its instance variables is created for this user only, static fields will be served from the memory for all users.
- Controller's Service is called. So this Service is created for this user too.
- Return static list to this user. This will not increase my memory 14KB, because it is already in the heap.
- But my memory is increasing 30 KB for each request.

I know this is too long for read but i tried to give all my experiences during this path. I'm a bit confused about improving my performance, since i realized that i have never thought about it. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: If this code works fine, then this question is off topic on Stack Overflow, but may be good for our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You're way too worried about performance, to the point that you're wondering if you shouldn't make your code less readable, incorrect, or impossible to test just to shove a few nanoseconds at the startup of your app. Make your code clean, readable and by the book. Spring architects worried about performance for you, and the JVM is very fast at collecting short-lived objects. Don't try to optimize when you don't have a performance problem. Your used heap starts at 100 MB, and falls back to 100MB after your 10K requests. Your CPU peaks at 40%. There is no problem.

Comment: By default Spring beans are created in the application scope, which means there is only one instance of that bean in the application context. So you will only have one instance of OpenStackBean and OpenStackService, regardless of the number of requests. Regarding the memory per connection, don't forget that the servlet container has to create objects per request like HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. For the rest of the points, i agree with JB Nizet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was worrying about how memory is increasing, just wanted to understand the workflow from lower perspective

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In this case I will be injecting those configurations as instance. 2) So every class (lets say i have 10.000 users in a minute and this
>      class will be created 10.000 times) will create their own
>      configuration in the stack, will it and when it completes, deletes it,
>      so memory is free again. 3) But because there will be so many request,
>      doesn't it make memory problems?

No it will not be a problem. Spring beans are by default "Singleton" scope (except you explicitly set another scope), so only one instance of **OpenStackBean** will be created. 
So there is no need to create static field.

> So why heap increases 300MB (from 100 to 400) after 10000 requests? This means 30 KB is created in the memory for every requests.

Because tomcat need to create many temporary objects to handle the request, but they will be gone after request have been served (Also note that you won't see decrease in heap usage because java only remove unused objects after Garbage collection)

> Controller's Service is called. So this Service is created for this
>   user too.

That's also false, if your controller is Singletone scope, it's created only once.

> What exactly happens when a request comes to an endpoint? Are all instance variables of the APP will be created or only visited classes will be created?

Of curse not! when tomcat serve your request, only required calsses need to be instantiated.

In general, you are over concerning about performance issues. the thing that you should be concerned is when an object is not removed from memory (Memory usage increased and not decreased after GC untill application crash). Also concerning memory footprint is real, but not about a few small objects created and destroyed through minor GCs.